# Key and Index Design for Effective Dated History Table(s)

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm fairly new to SQL database design and architecture. I am creating a table to hold 6 months-worth of daily snapshot files from my source system. A truncated version of the data table can be created with this script:

```
CREATE TABLE AccountHist 
(
    EffectiveDate datetime not null,
    AccountNumber bigint not null,
    Balance float not null,
    Status char(3) not null,
    IntRate real not null,
  etc......
)
```

EffectiveDate and AccountNumber together are unique and should never be duplicated, so I want to add a PK constraint to the table, but I'm confused on whether it should be CLUSTERED or NONCLUSETERD:

```
CONSTRAINT PK_AcctEffDate PRIMARY KEY (?) (EffectiveDate, AccountNumber)
```

I have a by-the-book-definition understanding of the differences between clustered and nonclustered indexes. I feel like I should use clustered because, well, that's what I see as being most common, but it also makes sense to have the data sorted by EffectiveDate.

What's tripping me up is that I think I also need nonclustered indexes for both EffectiveDate and AccountNumber. Here are 2 common queries I expect to run:

```
select AccountNumber, Balance from AccountHist
where EffectiveDate = (select max(EffectiveDate) from AccountHist)
and Status = 'ACT'
```

and

```
select EffectiveDate, Avg(IntRate) AvgRate from AccountHist
where EffectiveDate >= '01/01/2019' and EffectiveDate < '02/01/2019'
group by EffectiveDate
```

This boils down to three main questions:
1. Can I create separate indexes on the 2 columns that also make up my PK? If so, which should be clustered vs nonclustered?
2. Should I use a surrogate key instead? 
3. Which setup will yield the best performance in querying and in loading data?

Thanks.

Comment: Step 1 seems to be use the correct datatypes. Effective Date sounds like a date based on your description, not a datetime. To answer your questions - 1: yes but no one can say at this point, 2: no unless you have a reason. do you? 3: Impossible to say. You ask depends on how the table is populated over time and how it is queried. I'm sure you will get suggestions to add an identity column, make it the primary key, and cluster on it. But you have only one clustered index and you need to choose it wisely. Search the web for clustering criteria.

Comment: And 2 sample queries is not really sufficient to provide guidance. Lastly, you will likely regret using floating point datatypes for values that are usually strictly defined. Be careful about choosing real/float. A column named balance implies a monetary amount - accountant holders don't generally like to lose pennies due to rounding.

Comment: And one last comment. Your first sample query is "suspicious". Be careful what you assume here about how "balances" are generated and stored over time. Do you assume that rows will exist for every date from some starting point going forward? That implies a very strict process that must occur daily (or at least generate daily rows).

Comment: @SMor The table will have 25 columns and I didn't want to list all of them. The source system produces an extract file every day with every column and it's respective balance, status, rate, etc. at that point in time regardless if anything changes. There are no day-to-day gaps. Accounts never disappear, they only add. The extract process from source system is persistent, automated, and managed by 3rd party.

Comment: @SMor Noted on data type for Balance.